# Android: Let Users Access One Google Drive account

Tags: android, google-drive-api

What I need is for all my users to access one Google drive account which has files they need to access? Is there any way I can do this? Or should this be done in another way?

Comment: show us what you tried so far. its unclear what you want. why setting the content to public isnt enough?

Comment: You can share a document to "anyone who has the link" seems like that should work. I don't think there's a way to share the account except by sharing the password which is a really bad idea and probably against the terms of service.